# Magento 1.8 Not Doing Calculations for ZIP+4

Tags: magento-1.8, tax

I searched around and found several references to this core modification ([Magento Tax Calculation on Zip + 4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/587/magento-tax-calculation-on-zip-4)) to prevent Magento from not calculating US sales tax when ZIP code is supplied with ZIP+4 data, but it seems to be out of date.

It seems that the entire calculation method has changed in the time since the linked solution was created and shared, and I don't know where to implement this kind of fix anymore. I'm also not too "comfortable" with editing core files, etc.

Can anyone help me fix this problem with CE 1.8 ?

```
 */
class Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Rates cache
     *
     * @var unknown
     */
    protected $_ratesCache              = array();

    /**
     * Primery key auto increment flag
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isPkAutoIncrement    = false;

    /**
     * Resource initialization
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_setMainTable('tax/tax_calculation');
    }

    /**
     * Delete calculation settings by rule id
     *
     * @param int $ruleId
     * @return Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation
     */
    public function deleteByRuleId($ruleId)
    {
        $conn = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $where = $conn->quoteInto('tax_calculation_rule_id = ?', (int)$ruleId);
        $conn->delete($this->getMainTable(), $where);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retreive distinct calculation
     *
     * @param  string $field
     * @param  int $ruleId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDistinct($field, $ruleId)
    {
        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select();
        $select->from($this->getMainTable(), $field)
            ->where('tax_calculation_rule_id = ?', (int)$ruleId);

        return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol($select);
    }

    /**
     * Get tax rate information: calculation process data and tax rate
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRateInfo($request)
    {
        $rates = $this->_getRates($request);
        return array(
            'process'   => $this->getCalculationProcess($request, $rates),
            'value'     => $this->_calculateRate($rates)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get tax rate for specific tax rate request
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRate($request)
    {
        return $this->_calculateRate($this->_getRates($request));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Calculation Process
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @param array $rates
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCalculationProcess($request, $rates = null)
    {
        if (is_null($rates)) {
            $rates = $this->_getRates($request);
        }

        $result = array();
        $row = array();
        $ids = array();
        $currentRate = 0;
        $totalPercent = 0;
        $countedRates = count($rates);
        for ($i = 0; $i  $rate['code'],
                'title' => $rate['title'],
                'percent' => $value,
                'position' => $rate['position'],
                'priority' => $rate['priority'],
            );
            if (isset($rate['tax_calculation_rule_id'])) {
                $oneRate['rule_id'] = $rate['tax_calculation_rule_id'];
            }

            if (isset($rate['hidden'])) {
                $row['hidden'] = $rate['hidden'];
            }

            if (isset($rate['amount'])) {
                $row['amount'] = $rate['amount'];
            }

            if (isset($rate['base_amount'])) {
                $row['base_amount'] = $rate['base_amount'];
            }
            if (isset($rate['base_real_amount'])) {
                $row['base_real_amount'] = $rate['base_real_amount'];
            }
            $row['rates'][] = $oneRate;

            if (isset($rates[$i + 1]['tax_calculation_rule_id'])) {
                $rule = $rate['tax_calculation_rule_id'];
            }
            $priority = $rate['priority'];
            $ids[] = $rate['code'];

            if (isset($rates[$i + 1]['tax_calculation_rule_id'])) {
                while (isset($rates[$i + 1]) && $rates[$i + 1]['tax_calculation_rule_id'] == $rule) {
                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $currentRate += $value;

            if (!isset($rates[$i + 1]) || $rates[$i + 1]['priority'] != $priority
                || (isset($rates[$i + 1]['process']) && $rates[$i + 1]['process'] != $rate['process'])
            ) {
                if (!empty($rates[$i]['calculate_subtotal'])) {
                    $row['percent'] = $currentRate;
                    $totalPercent += $currentRate;
                } else {
                    $row['percent'] = $this->_collectPercent($totalPercent, $currentRate);
                    $totalPercent += $row['percent'];
                }
                $row['id'] = implode($ids);
                $result[] = $row;
                $row = array();
                $ids = array();

                $currentRate = 0;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Return combined percent value
     *
     * @param float|int $percent
     * @param float|int $rate
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _collectPercent($percent, $rate)
    {
        return (100 + $percent) * ($rate / 100);
    }

    /**
     * Create search templates for postcode
     *
     * @param string $postcode
     * @return array  $strArr
     */
    protected function _createSearchPostCodeTemplates($postcode)
    {
        $len = Mage::helper('tax')->getPostCodeSubStringLength();
        $strlen = strlen($postcode);
        if ($strlen > $len) {
            $postcode = substr($postcode, 0, $len);
            $strlen = $len;
        }

        $strArr = array($postcode, $postcode . '*');
        if ($strlen > 1) {
            for ($i = 1; $i getStore($request->getStore())->getId();
        $customerClassId = $request->getCustomerClassId();
        $countryId = $request->getCountryId();
        $regionId = $request->getRegionId();
        $postcode = $request->getPostcode();

        // Process productClassId as it can be array or usual value. Form best key for cache.
        $productClassId = $request->getProductClassId();
        $ids = is_array($productClassId) ? $productClassId : array($productClassId);
        foreach ($ids as $key => $val) {
            $ids[$key] = (int) $val; // Make it integer for equal cache keys even in case of null/false/0 values
        }
        $ids = array_unique($ids);
        sort($ids);
        $productClassKey = implode(',', $ids);

        // Form cache key and either get data from cache or from DB
        $cacheKey = implode('|', array($storeId, $customerClassId, $productClassKey, $countryId, $regionId, $postcode));

        if (!isset($this->_ratesCache[$cacheKey])) {
            // Make SELECT and get data
            $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select();
            $select
                ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()),
                array('tax_calculation_rate_id',
                      'tax_calculation_rule_id',
                      'customer_tax_class_id',
                      'product_tax_class_id'
                    )
                )
                ->where('customer_tax_class_id = ?', (int)$customerClassId);
            if ($productClassId) {
                $select->where('product_tax_class_id IN (?)', $productClassId);
            }
            $ifnullTitleValue = $this->_getReadAdapter()->getCheckSql(
                'title_table.value IS NULL',
                'rate.code',
                'title_table.value'
            );
            $ruleTableAliasName = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('rule.tax_calculation_rule_id');
            $select
                ->join(
                    array('rule' => $this->getTable('tax/tax_calculation_rule')),
                    $ruleTableAliasName . ' = main_table.tax_calculation_rule_id',
                    array('rule.priority', 'rule.position', 'rule.calculate_subtotal'))
                ->join(
                    array('rate' => $this->getTable('tax/tax_calculation_rate')),
                    'rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = main_table.tax_calculation_rate_id',
                    array(
                        'value' => 'rate.rate',
                        'rate.tax_country_id',
                        'rate.tax_region_id',
                        'rate.tax_postcode',
                        'rate.tax_calculation_rate_id',
                        'rate.code'
                ))
                ->joinLeft(
                    array('title_table' => $this->getTable('tax/tax_calculation_rate_title')),
                   "rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = title_table.tax_calculation_rate_id "
                   . "AND title_table.store_id = '{$storeId}'",
                    array('title' => $ifnullTitleValue))
                ->where('rate.tax_country_id = ?', $countryId)
                ->where("rate.tax_region_id IN(?)", array(0, (int)$regionId));
            $postcodeIsNumeric = is_numeric($postcode);
            $postcodeIsRange = is_string($postcode) && preg_match('/^(.+)-(.+)$/', $postcode, $matches);
            if ($postcodeIsRange) {
                $zipFrom = $matches[1];
                $zipTo = $matches[2];
            }

            if ($postcodeIsNumeric || $postcodeIsRange) {
                $selectClone = clone $select;
                $selectClone->where('rate.zip_is_range IS NOT NULL');
            }
            $select->where('rate.zip_is_range IS NULL');

            if ($postcode != '*' || $postcodeIsRange) {
                $select
                    ->where("rate.tax_postcode IS NULL OR rate.tax_postcode IN('*', '', ?)",
                        $postcodeIsRange ? $postcode : $this->_createSearchPostCodeTemplates($postcode));
                if ($postcodeIsNumeric) {
                    $selectClone
                        ->where('? BETWEEN rate.zip_from AND rate.zip_to', $postcode);
                } else if ($postcodeIsRange) {
                    $selectClone->where('rate.zip_from >= ?', $zipFrom)
                        ->where('rate.zip_to _getReadAdapter()->select()->union(
                    array(
                        '(' . $select . ')',
                        '(' . $selectClone . ')'
                    )
                );
            }

            $select->order('priority ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
                   ->order('tax_calculation_rule_id ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
                   ->order('tax_country_id ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC)
                   ->order('tax_region_id ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC)
                   ->order('tax_postcode ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC)
                   ->order('value ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC);

            $this->_ratesCache[$cacheKey] = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
        }

        return $this->_ratesCache[$cacheKey];
    }

    /**
     * Calculate rate
     *
     * @param array $rates
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _calculateRate($rates)
    {
        $result      = 0;
        $currentRate = 0;
        $countedRates = count($rates);
        for ($i = 0; $i _collectPercent($result, $currentRate);
                }
                $currentRate = 0;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve rate ids
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRateIds($request)
    {
        $result = array();
        $rates  = $this->_getRates($request);
        $countedRates = count($rates);
        for ($i = 0; $i _getReadAdapter();
        $customerTaxClassId = (int)$customerTaxClass;
        $calcJoinConditions = array(
            'calc_table.tax_calculation_rate_id = main_table.tax_calculation_rate_id',
            $adapter->quoteInto('calc_table.customer_tax_class_id = ?', $customerTaxClassId),

        );
        if ($productTaxClass !== null) {
            $productTaxClassId = (int)$productTaxClass;
            $calcJoinConditions[] = $adapter->quoteInto('calc_table.product_tax_class_id = ?', $productTaxClassId);
        }

        $selectCSP = $adapter->select();
        $selectCSP
            ->from(
                array('main_table' => $this->getTable('tax/tax_calculation_rate')),
                array('country' => 'tax_country_id', 'region_id' => 'tax_region_id', 'postcode' => 'tax_postcode'))
            ->joinInner(
                array('calc_table' => $this->getTable('tax/tax_calculation')),
                implode(' AND ', $calcJoinConditions),
                array('product_class' => 'calc_table.product_tax_class_id'))
            ->joinLeft(
                array('state_table' => $this->getTable('directory/country_region')),
                'state_table.region_id = main_table.tax_region_id',
                array('region_code' => 'state_table.code'))
            ->distinct(true);

        $CSP = $adapter->fetchAll($selectCSP);

        $result = array();
        foreach ($CSP as $one) {
            $request = new Varien_Object();
            $request->setCountryId($one['country'])
                ->setRegionId($one['region_id'])
                ->setPostcode($one['postcode'])
                ->setCustomerClassId($customerTaxClassId)
                ->setProductClassId($one['product_class']);

            $rate = $this->getRate($request);
            if ($rate) {
                $row = array(
                    'value'         => $rate/100,
                    'country'       => $one['country'],
                    'state'         => $one['region_code'],
                    'postcode'      => $one['postcode'],
                    'product_class' => $one['product_class'],
                );

                $result[] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you need is to copy the following file:
    `/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php`

and place it in 
    `/app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php`

and then find the following code
`protected $_postCodeSubStringLength = 10;`

 around `line #110`  and replace 10 with your desired length.

and if that doesn't work, then revert the changes and copy your own mentioned file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php
```

and place it in

```
app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php
```

find the code `$postcode = $request->getPostcode();` around line #254 within function `protected function _getRates($request)` and replace the code with `$postcode = substr($request->getPostcode(),0,5);` or you can even use the condition if you want this code to work for `US` only:

```
$postcode = $request->getPostcode();
if($countryId == 'US'){
     substr($request->getPostcode(), 0, 5);
}
```

replace 5 with your desired length.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that Calculation.php is no longer "compatible" with the solution I mentioned above. There is no _getRates() function...although there are similar functions that seem to be doing roughly the same thing(s). I'm just not sure where to make the modifications, etc. 
It seems to compare two zipcodes and then calculate the tax off of one of them if they're not the same...
I do like your suggestion regarding $countryId tho. Thanks for that.

Comment: the code that i mentioned is of magento 1.8, I searched and suggeted.

Comment: can you post your Calculation.php by editing your question.

Comment: @g-man1066, this is not the file actually, please paste the code of the file `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php` in the question.

Comment: OK... now I see what's going on... I had the wrong Calculation.php file....