# How to remove tax on product on in specific condition

Tags: checkout, tax

Hello Friends I want to remove the tax of the product in specific condition.I tried to set taxclass id as 0 but it adds the total of tax and product orice I want to completely remove the tax please help .
Currently this is my code which I used to remove tax

```
 $tax=Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');        
 $inc_tax=$product->getPrice();
 $exc_tax=$inc_tax-$tax;$product->setPrice($exc_tax);
 $finalPrice=$exc_tax;
 $product->setTaxClassId(0);
```

Please help me .

Comment: I have the same issue. This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457778/make-a-checkout-session-tax-exempt-based-on-session-conditions

Comment: Sorry dude it didnt worked for me @DushyantJoshi

Comment: Another promising link.Look for method function _getRates($request)
 http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/587/magento-tax-calculation-on-zip-4

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an observer `sales_quote_add_item`

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

Then reset the values that charges tax

```
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();

    $quote_item->setTaxPercent(0);
    $quote_item->setTaxAmount(0);
    $quote_item->setBaseTaxAmount(0);

    $quote_item->setPriceInclTax($quote_item->getPrice());
    $quote_item->setBasePriceInclTax($quote_item->getBasePrice());
    $quote_item->setBaseRowTotalInclTax($quote_item->setBaseRowTotal());

    $quote_item->save();
}
```

See [Changing the price in quote while adding product to cart: magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento)